# PWA on Github pages

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on PWA on my page, and I'm following 100% this simple codelab - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#0 and everything works fine (on exmaple code used, and also on my own webpage), but only when i test it on localhost.
after deploying it on github pages, i got lots of errors:

1. `GET https://[myusername].github.io/manifest.json 404 ()` (ie.
   there may be something wrong with paths, as there should be project name before manifest file i guess)
2. `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.` (in devtools i can see there's  although it's normal json file and it's working fine on my localhost);
3. `TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad
   HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`
4. and after clicking "Add to homescreen" in devtools, i got: `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.` and `Site cannot be installed: the manifest could not be fetched, is empty, or could not be parsed`.

Any ideas? I don't know if i'm doing something wrong or there's something wrong with github pages...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the `service-worker.js` and `manifest.json` files may have gotten corrupted somehow, because I can't open either file on my computer even with multiple downloads. (I'm looking at the `/final` folder)

I'd also suggest looking at other PWA's already on Github, such as [pwarocks](https://github.com/pwarocks/pwa.rocks) to see how they've pulled off a PWA using Github Pages.

Comment: Well, for me the files itself are working fine (+ new files in my own project, based on this tutorial), but only on localhost testing, not after publishing on github. Probably i should check another source, but this seems to be the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

The root path of Github Pages is the user name <sup>`https://{github_username}.github.io/{repository}`</sup>, which means that if your repository is to become a PWA, then the `start_url` in `manifest.json` should be adjusted accordingly, and your other paths that point to the root path, such as `/` should also be given the repository name `/repo/` to work correctly.

for example

manifest.json

```
{
  // ...
  "id": "/repository/", // not "/"
  "start_url": "/repository/", // if you set "/" that means: `https://{github_username}.github.io/` not `https://{github_username}.github.io/repository`
}
```

app.js

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/repository/sw.js') // not '/sw.js'
```

#### Full example

- source: https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/twenty48/tree/gh-pages/docs
- demo: https://carsonslovoka.github.io/twenty48/